# Dropdown option that include all values, saving to database as FK

Tags: asp.net, foreign-keys

Let's say I have a table "Products" with 3 products ID: 1, 2 and 3.

Then in my asp.net app, I have a dropdown to select the product with these options:

- Product 1 (with value 1)
- Product 2 (with value 2)
- Product 3 (with value 3)
- Any product (with value 0)

If "any product" is selected, I return the SQL query that matches any of the 3 products.

On the other side, I also have to save each of these searches too.

As the "Searches" table has a FK of ProductID the question is:

Is it OK to save the searches of "Any product" with a NULL value in ProductID? Because it's a FK and I've been reading FK should not be null.

I'm not sure if there is a better way (I don't want to enter a new product called "Any product" to the table Products, it does not make sense to me).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could do as you say, BUT, when you say that the productid in the searches table is a foreign key, do you actually have a constraint for the foreign key? because if you do, you won't be able to enter null (or any other value for that matter) that doesn't exist in the product table.

you could create a dummy product with Id -1 for example, and when you select the products from the table, you just have to ignore the one with Id -1.

Comment: Depends which database is being used - some allow NULL as a valid entry for columns for a FK constraint.

Comment: Thank you.

I use SQL Server.

I did not set the FK yet, so I'm not sure if SQL Server allows nulls.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe my design is wrong and I should split the searches tables in two tables saving the 3 products when they select the "any products option". This way if someday I also change the dropdown for other control that allow to select two products I could save both. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, it is not a good idea to set to null your ProductID field. Setting a foreign key to null habitually indicate that the referenced field had been deleted or updated.

Knowing what exactly is the purpose of your Searches table would help to find a solution to your problem.  But my guess is that you should treat this scenario in your code, not in the database.

Comment: but he needs to keep track of searches per product so he needs to store the value somewhere.

Comment: The solution you proposed would then be a good one. With a negative product ID, a trace of the search can be tracked in the searches table. Also, other search types can be defined (via an enum) and be also tracked.

Comment: Still thinking, I think I cannot use NULL or -1. If I do it that way, I would be supposing that when -1 would always mean Products 1, 2 and 3. But if in the future I add a Product 4, I won't be able to know what products belong the old searches (I mean, 4 does not belong to the old searches and the -1 or NULL is indicating "any products"). I think I'll need two tables.